# node-module to convert multi images tiff into multipages tiff

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tiff, libtiff

I want to merge multiple tiff images into one single tiff image using nodejs/javascript.

How to get single tiff having multi-pages for multiple tiff images in nodejs?
Is there any way to convert pdf of multiple pages into one tiff image in nodejs?

Comment: Do you mean that  you want to make a collage?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158750/can-you-combine-multiple-images-into-a-single-one-using-javascript : Might be what you are looking for. Please be more clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to find a solution to this as well and what I learned is that there isn't really a great option. Anything you do, no matter what, will require semi-annoying dependency installations depending on where you are deploying your solution.  Also, they will all use some variation of imagemagick or graphicsmagick or libtiff or some other variant I haven't seen yet.

I made a quick setup that will programmatically download image magick binaries and setup correct environment variables and paths to run imagemagick's `convert` cli tool programmatically through a node.js spawn command.  You can check out the full repo here:
https://github.com/wolfejw86/tiff-images-playground

The short answer is this though:

1. get image magick or libtiff binaries into your environment
2. ensure your running node.js process has access to those
3. call the binary directly with `child_process`'s `.spawn` method or use something like the `gm` npm module - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm - that depends on the binary you need.